# getting connection string name in azure worker role

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-runtime

I am currently injection the concrete ConfigFileSettings of the IConfigFileSettings into classes that require a name for the connection string. The simplified code looks as follows:

```
public interface IConfigFileSettings
{
    string GetConnectionString(string name);
}

public class ConfigFileSettings : IConfigFileSettings
{
    public string GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].Name;
    }
}
```

This works fine for webapi's hosted in iis, windows services and console application. I guess:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].Name
```

won't work in worker roles. Can I adapt the GetConnectionString method to make it work in all environments transparently? Also even if I get the connection sting name (e.g. from a .cscfg file) my code will look for:

```
<connectionStrings> ... </connectionStrings>
```

I guess I cannot just add an  entry into the .cscfg file?

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in the .cscfg file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Web.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <Role name="Worker">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="connectionstringname" value="connectionstringvalue" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Then you can read them by:

```
var connectionstring = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("connectionstringname");
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to make this work in all environment though. I think one can use RoleEnvironment to detect which environment I am in. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

[This is a small utility for strong typed config in azure](https://github.com/ognyandim/AzureStrongConfig) implemented with [Castle Windsor DictionaryAdapter](http://kozmic.net/2014/03/22/strongly-typed-app-settings-with-castle-dictionaryadapter/). I use it in my projects. Usage :

1. Explore the code a bit to get the idea
2. Define your strongly typed config interfaces - Look at Configuration.Interfaces assembly
3. Define your factories / use azure config provider in composition root and use dictionary adapter to fill the config dictionaries -
4. Inject your config like in MyWorkerService.cs

   using Configuration.Interfaces;
   using Persistence.Interfaces;
   using Worker.Services.Interfaces;

   namespace Worker.Services
   {
       public class MyWorkerService : IMyWorkerService
       {
           private readonly IConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;
           private readonly IAzureServiceConfiguration _azureServiceConfiguration;
           private readonly IMicrosoftStorageConfig _microsoftStorageConfig;
           private readonly IPersitenceServiceConfigDependent _persitenceServiceConfigDependent;
           private readonly IAppConfigSettings _appConfigSettings;

   ```
   public MyWorkerService(
       IPersitenceServiceConfigDependent persitenceServiceConfigDependent,

       IConnectionStrings connectionStrings,
       IAzureServiceConfiguration azureServiceConfiguration,
       IMicrosoftStorageConfig microsoftStorageConfig,
       IAppConfigSettings appConfigSettings)
   {
       _connectionStrings = connectionStrings;
       _azureServiceConfiguration = azureServiceConfiguration;
       _microsoftStorageConfig = microsoftStorageConfig;
       _persitenceServiceConfigDependent = persitenceServiceConfigDependent;
       _appConfigSettings = appConfigSettings;
   }

   public string DoWork()
   {
       _persitenceServiceConfigDependent.ConfigDependentAction("blah");
       var configSetting = _microsoftStorageConfig.StorageConnectionString;
       return $"Job done :" +
              $" <br> msConfig : {configSetting}, " +
              $" <br> azureConfig.ServiceBusConnectionString:{_azureServiceConfiguration.ServiceBusConnectionString} " +
              $" <br> webConfig.SubscriptionId:{_appConfigSettings.SubscriptionId} " +
              $" <br> connectionStrings.DefaultConnection :{_connectionStrings.DefaultConnection}";
   }
   ```

   }
   }